# Unix Shell scripting in AIX(Sed command)

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a text file which consists of jobname,business name and time in min seperated with '-'(SfdcDataGovSeq-IntegraterJob-43).There are many jobs in this text file. I want to search with the jobname and change the time from 43 to 0 only for that particular row and update the same text file. Kindly advise what needs to be done.

Query that i am using : (cat test.txt | grep "SfdcDataGovSeq" | sed -e 's/43/0/' > test.txt) but the whole file is getting replaced with only one line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour]. You could improve readability of your question with some formatting options. Otherwise nice mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e '/SfdcDataGovSeq/ s/43/0/' test.txt
```

This will only replace if the search is positive.

Agreed with Ed, Here is a workaround to put word boundaries Although Equality with `awk` is robust.

```
sed -e '/SfdcDataGovSeq/ s/\<43\>/0/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Does it replace the 43 only in that particular line or replaces all the '43' values present in that file with 0.

Comment: it will replace only on the lines which  contain '`SfdcDataGovSeq`' in it.

Comment: Since the jobnames are distinct so it only operates on one line, then it is definitely helpful

Comment: That will change lines that start with `fooSfdcDataGovSeq` and will change `143` to `10`, etc. There's workarounds but seds the wrong tool for this job, you should be using awk.

Comment: it is only getting displayed on screeon

Comment: I want it to get changed in the file

Comment: use `sed -i` flag or `sed -e '/SfdcDataGovSeq/ s/43/0/' input.txt> input.txt.tmp && mv input.txt.tmp input.txt`

Comment: yes,if your `sed` supports `-i` flag then it should. @nd option must work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using awk instead of sed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} $1=="SfdcDataGovSeq" && $3==43{$3=0} 1' file
```

Since it does full string or numeric (not regexp) matches on specific fields, the above is far more robust than the currently accepted sed answer which would wreak havoc on your input file given various possible input values.

Comment: Hi Ed, can you explain  "{FS=OFS="-"}

Comment: It's setting the input and output field separators to a "-" sign so your data gets split into "-"-separated fields, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators